# Hardhat-toolbox dependency error

Tags: solidity, hardhat

When I initialize the project with `yarn hardhat`, the warning errors come from yarn when I try to install hardhat-toolbox via `yarn add --dev @nomicfoundation/hardhat-toolbox`.

without that, I cannot even compile my solidity so that I have to install it despite an error here...

the warning error is here below:

```
[2/4] Fetching packages...
[3/4] Linking dependencies...
warning " > @nomicfoundation/hardhat-toolbox@2.0.2" has unmet peer dependency "@ethersproject/abi@^5.4.7".
warning " > @nomicfoundation/hardhat-toolbox@2.0.2" has unmet peer dependency "@ethersproject/providers@^5.4.7".
warning " > @nomicfoundation/hardhat-toolbox@2.0.2" has unmet peer dependency "@nomicfoundation/hardhat-network-helpers@^1.0.0".
warning " > @nomicfoundation/hardhat-toolbox@2.0.2" has unmet peer dependency "@nomicfoundation/hardhat-chai-matchers@^1.0.0".
warning " > @nomicfoundation/hardhat-toolbox@2.0.2" has unmet peer dependency "@nomiclabs/hardhat-ethers@^2.0.0".
warning " > @nomicfoundation/hardhat-toolbox@2.0.2" has unmet peer dependency "@nomiclabs/hardhat-etherscan@^3.0.0".
warning " > @nomicfoundation/hardhat-toolbox@2.0.2" has unmet peer dependency "@typechain/ethers-v5@^10.1.0".
warning " > @nomicfoundation/hardhat-toolbox@2.0.2" has unmet peer dependency "@typechain/hardhat@^6.1.2".
warning " > @nomicfoundation/hardhat-toolbox@2.0.2" has unmet peer dependency "ethers@^5.4.7".
warning " > @nomicfoundation/hardhat-toolbox@2.0.2" has unmet peer dependency "hardhat-gas-reporter@^1.0.8".
warning " > @nomicfoundation/hardhat-toolbox@2.0.2" has unmet peer dependency "solidity-coverage@^0.8.1".
warning " > @nomicfoundation/hardhat-toolbox@2.0.2" has unmet peer dependency "typechain@^8.1.0".
```

how can I eliminate those errors?
do I have to re-install all those dependencies? thank you in advance.